# Conditionally apply evaluated expression class name?

Tags: angularjs

I originally had this, and it was easy: `ng-class="response.name"`
(Where `response.name` was an evaluated expression.)

But now I'm trying to do this: `ng-class="{response.name: true, tooltip: someExpression}"` (So that `response.name` is always there but `tooltip` is context-dependent.)

You see, I can't have `response.name` as a key in the object...I know this. It just treats it as the string `response.name` literally and there's no evaluation. But I need the `tooltip` class to be applied conditionally. I don't know how to combine these needs!

I first tried simply using multiple ng-class attributes, but it just ignored all but the first.

Comment: did you tried the combination `ng-if` with `ng-class`

Comment: I figured it out. Will post answer when it lets me. It's not too tricky but kind of neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this

```
<div ng-class="{tooltip: someExpression}" class="{{response.name}}"></div>
```

Just make sure you test it in all the browsers you are supporting as dynamically setting attributes like this can cause problems with some browsers

Comment: Oh nice that's a great idea too.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW: As of Angular 1.4 you can mix expressions:

```
ng-class="[response.name, {tooltip: someExpression}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-class allows you to to this:

```
<div ng-class="[response.name, {tooltip: someExpression}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally solved it with this hideousness:

```
{ {{ response.name }}: true, 'tooltip-container': {{ !!response.tooltip }} }
```

Evaluated expressions interpolated into an evaluated expression. Ugly. Definitely favor Rob's way.